# Open pdf in new tab upon page loading

Tags: javascript, php, forms, pdf, onload

After submitting a form, the user is taken to a thank you page. On this page I create a variable containing the url to a specific floor plan they selected from the form.

```
$floorplan = $_POST['cm-f-djuiyhkr'];
```

I then want to open this floorplan pdf in a new tab after the thank you page has loaded. Currently this is what I have at the bottom of my document

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var link = '<?php echo $floorplan ?>';
        var newTab = window.open(link, '_blank');
    }, 5000);
});
}
  </script>
```

Obviously it's not working, and I am not good enough with code to debug it. I assume it is trouble mixing JS and PHP

Comment: No, it is much more likely your browser's popup blocker doing its job. Most browsers these days block popups by default, if you try to open them without explicit user interaction (like a click on a button or link.)

Comment: Would you have a suggestion as to a better way to make this work while avoiding popup blockers? For example, download the pdf instead of opening it in a tab?

Comment: A meta refresh (with the URL of the download) on the thank you page is the usual approach.